# Bot Framework Event for Postbacks?

Tags: node.js, event-handling, botframework, botkit, adaptive-cards

My question:

I have an adaptive card with a postback button whose value is say "thisIsMyPostback". Now, I want to act on this postback as one would.

The problem is that this postback can also be typed out to reach the same result. In other words, clicking the button and also just messaging my bot "thisIsMyPostback" straight up result in the same thing.

Is there a way to separate a postback message from a 'message_received'? That way a user messaging "thisIsMyPostback" straight up would not result in the same thing as clicking the button.

Thanks!

Comment: @Fabian can you either post a code sample here or put it in a public repo so we can take a look?

Comment: He is using node (per the question tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adaptive Cards readme on the BotFramework WebChat GitHub repo [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/adaptivecards/AdaptiveCards.md) states:

> The data property of the action may be a string or it may
>   be an object. A string is passed back to your bot as a Bot Builder SDK
>   imBack activity, and an object is passed as a postBack activity.
>   Activities with imBack appear in the chat stream as a user-entered
>   reply. The postBack activities are not displayed.

```
"actions": [
          {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Next",
            "data": { "postBack": "thisIsMyPostback" }
          }
        ]
```

If the value of the Activity doesn't have an object, then the user did not click the button.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to separate a postback message from a 'message_received'? That way a user messaging "thisIsMyPostback" straight up would not result in the same thing as clicking the button.

No, it's not currently possible, because all messages, user or imBack/postBack, are of type "message" so there's no way to tell the difference unless you put some special text in your postBack and configure a `triggerAction` to recognize it.

For more information on using trigger actions, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-global-handlers#trigger-a-help-dialog